# Text mining in C#

Tags: c#, text-mining

Is there any C# open source library for analyzing text and categorize them in categories, capable of customizing for different language.

I expect learning phase from the library which create vector space from words and indicate which word is for example a Person or Organization or a Place, etc. and based on the created database recognize and extracting main characteristic of text.

Comment: Assuming `them` refers to individual words or sentences in the text, according to which criteria do you wish to categorize them?

Comment: meaning direction for example (sport, social, politic, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sentences/words/phrases/etc .. there is a service you can call .. opencalais.com, it attempts to identify entities within text. Also, you may want to look into the natural language toolkit .. nltk.org .. hope this helps .. also, you may find more of what you are looking for using "data mining"